# Lru Cache listView image issues

Tags: java, android, android-lru-cache

I've my ListView with images on my activity, works great till I add the LRU Cache. When I load for the first time (if i don't scroll it) while the images are loading the first element change its image between all the images i was loading.

My LRU Cache looks like

```
public class Image {
    private static LruCache<String, Bitmap>     mMemoryCache    = null;
    private static int                          cacheSize       = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    private static class AsyncLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView   mTarget;

        public AsyncLoader(ImageView target) {
            this.mTarget = target;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mTarget.setTag(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls) {
            String url = urls[0];

            Bitmap result = null;

            if (url != null) {
                result = load(url);

                if (result != null) {
                    mMemoryCache.put(url, result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (mTarget.getTag() == this) {
                mTarget.setTag(null);
                if (result != null) mTarget.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap load(String urlString) {
        if (urlString == null || urlString.length() == 0) return null;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static void loadToView(String url, ImageView view) {
        if (url == null || url.length() == 0) return;
        if (mMemoryCache == null) {
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return (bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());
                }
            };
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(url);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            final AsyncLoader task = (AsyncLoader) new AsyncLoader(view);
            view.setTag(task);
            task.execute(url);
        } else {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Image.loadToView("http://image_url", (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail));
```

This is how looks my BaseAdapter getView

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)).setText(filtered_data.get(position).name);

    Image.loadToView("http://graph.facebook.com/" + filtered_data.get(position).id + "/picture", (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: try to set null to imageview while it's downoloading

Comment: but I want to have a default image if doesn't exists? I will try this anyway...

Comment: Can you show `getView` method from adapter?

Comment: updated, I just use a static method to set the image url and the view, if I load just without the Lru Cache it works fine..

Comment: Your getView method is not very efficent. You should better return the view from the arguments.

Comment: changed the return view, but the issue persist, seems that the item list it removed and rendered again when it comes visible again, dont know if there is a LRU cache lib that I can use instead or an working example so I try to figure out how to solve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I it figure out reading a lot about image on listview issues, its related to the listview recycling, some related post:

- [Android Listview AsyncTask image problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287412/android-listview-asynctask-image-problem)
- [Android listview image loading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977935/android-listview-image-loading-problem)

What I've added is the else statement in the onPostExecute method, if the tag isn't the one setted on tag I cancel it.

The fixed code its

```
public class Image {
    private static LruCache<String, Bitmap>     mMemoryCache    = null;
    private static int                          cacheSize       = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    private static class AsyncLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView   mTarget;

        public AsyncLoader(ImageView target) {
            this.mTarget = target;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mTarget.setTag(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls) {
            String url = urls[0];

            Bitmap result = null;

            if (url != null) {
                result = load(url);

                if (result != null) {
                    mMemoryCache.put(url, result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (mTarget.getTag() == this) {
                mTarget.setTag(null);
                if (result != null) mTarget.setImageBitmap(result);
            } else if (mTarget.getTag() != null) {
                ((AsyncLoader) mTarget.getTag()).cancel(true);
                mTarget.setTag(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap load(String urlString) {
        if (urlString == null || urlString.length() == 0) return null;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static void loadToView(String url, ImageView view) {
        if (url == null || url.length() == 0) return;
        if (mMemoryCache == null) {
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return (bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());
                }
            };
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(url);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            final AsyncLoader task = (AsyncLoader) new AsyncLoader(view);
            view.setTag(task);
            task.execute(url);
        } else {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

I think google need to fix this or provide a much cleaner workaround, because of the (in my opinion) failure of google on build something where developers only need to care about build their own apps and not to lose their time finding ways to fix the sdk issues